# What can be done if an approved edit breaks the question?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Yesterday somebody "corrected" the "grammar" of my question. I've put those words into quotation marks because he "fixed" a parameter name and even edited a typo into the question.

I felt quite trolled by this user.

Could I, as the author of the question, revert the edit or do I just have to start a potential edit war? The other question is why this edit got accepted at all...

Comment: When clicking on the "XYZ edited ZYX hours ago" you should see a "Rollback" option on the different versions of your post. You can use that. If an edit war starts you should flag the post for "moderator attention" and then describe what the problem is.

Comment: Just roll it back. It's probably just an innocent mistake, not someone trying to "troll" you. Assume no malice unless you are certain it's otherwise.

Comment: OK, maybe not trolling but it's obvious that this user wanted some cheap points by editing random stuff into a random post. The edit shouldn't have been approved at all as everybody saw that those were fixed variable names and the typo was obvious as well.

Comment: You had already [rolled the edit back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54940431/revisions)... hadn't you?

Comment: I kind of reverted it "manually"...

Comment: The question is more about how such edits should be handled in general.

Comment: IIRC, if the OP uses the rollback functionality, the editor loses those points. (Likely has to happen in a certain amount of time and be the last edit.) Not sure if that would apply in this case since one of the reviewers made an additional edit.

Comment: To be honest I didn't see a revert link. Maybe I was too late or it was too late and my eyes didn't work properly anymore... ;-)

Comment: Yeah, this whole edit was crap. I've rolled back to 1 for you.

Comment: @JL2210 As I mentioned above, this question is not about taking something as an offense or something like that, but about the general workflow in such cases! I found the Rollback link afterwards as well! Thanks for your help! That's what StackExchange should be about: helping each other!

Answer (score 16):

Such edits shouldn't be approved in first place. When they happen, use the roll-back link in the edit history.

If it is a very obvious wrong review, then you can also flag for moderator attention and ask the moderators to check the reviewer (but please only do this if the review is really really wrong or if there is a pattern of a reviewer).

Answer (score 10):

As the author of a post, you have a lot of control over it, even if you do not have the editing privileges yet. You can

- directly edit it
- roll back edits ([FAQ on how to do it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876))
- override it, if it was an approved edit ([Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028))

What action to take mostly depends on the edits made. Whether to directly edit it again or roll back the edit depends mostly on how much you disagree with the edits and what action causes you more work. If I agreed with most of the edits, then I'd probably directly edit the rest. If I disagreed with most of the edits, I'd probably roll back. Overriding an approved edit is a more drastic action. It means that you **reject** the edit. I'd probably only do it if I felt the edits weren't made in good faith and it got robo-approved.

If you disagree with an edit to your post and feel you have good reasons to, then don't hesitate to improve your post. Don't fear an edit war - if this happens, flag your post for moderator attention (custom flag, explain what's going on). The moderators can then handle it for you. This probably more of a problem if you roll back someone's edit who has the direct editing [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), not with suggested edits.